# Installed heroku-toolbelt with homebrew, and foreman isn't included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, homebrew, foreman, heroku-toolbelt

I'm using the homebrew package manager on Mac OSX, and I've installed the heroku-toolbelt package, which is supposed to include git, heroku CLI, and foreman. It only seems to include the first two:

```
$ brew info heroku-toolbelt
heroku-toolbelt: stable 3.20.0
https://toolbelt.heroku.com/other
/usr/local/Cellar/heroku-toolbelt/3.20.0 (438 files, 3.5M) *
Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/heroku-toolbelt.rb
$ which heroku
/usr/local/bin/heroku
$ which foreman
$ heroku --version
heroku-toolbelt/3.21.4 (x86_64-darwin13.0) ruby/2.1.2
$ foreman
bash: foreman: command not found
```

Any ideas why it's not appearing? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the **heroku-toolbelt** is installed through homebrew, you have the standalone version, as Daniel said.

If you like to install foreman as standalone as well, but with a package manager, you can install it as a gem:

```
gem install foreman
```

or

```
sudo gem install foreman
```

depending on how your ruby is setup.

More install info on foreman can be found on it's [homepage](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).

Answer (score 2):

The **heroku-toolbelt** being shipped within homebrew is the 'standalone' **[version](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone)**.
This version includes 'Heroku client' only.

What you can do is get the **Mac OS X** **[version](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/osx)**.
Then you can either use 'Heroku client' and 'Foreman' from there, or select to install 'Foreman' only (keeping the 'Heroku client' from homebrew).

Comment: Forgot one thing. You can also download foreman from the [source](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).

Answer (score 1):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/692
Starting August 12, 2015, new Heroku Toolbelt installs will not come with Foreman. The command `heroku local` has replaced foreman.